# ImportError: cannot import name 'Client' from 'plaid'

Tags: python, plaid

I have been struggling to find an answer. I am trying to integrate plaid with my django project, however I continue to get the same error. I am on python 3.11 and plaid 19.0.0.

I have tried various types of code, but it my troubles seem to be about the Client Library from Plaid. I am wondering if anyone has dealt with something similar. I have tried virtual environments and uninstalling, but to no avail.

The plaid-python package in in my python site packages where it shows:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Client' from 'plaid' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/plaid/__init__.py)
```

And the **init**.py file is:

```
"""
    The Plaid API

    The Plaid REST API. Please see https://plaid.com/docs/api for more details.  # noqa: E501

    The version of the OpenAPI document: 2020-09-14_1.496.2
    Generated by: https://openapi-generator.tech
"""


__version__ = "19.0.0"

# import ApiClient
from plaid.api_client import ApiClient

# import Configuration
from plaid.configuration import Configuration
# import Environments
from plaid.configuration import Environment

# import exceptions
from plaid.exceptions import OpenApiException
from plaid.exceptions import ApiAttributeError
from plaid.exceptions import ApiTypeError
from plaid.exceptions import ApiValueError
from plaid.exceptions import ApiKeyError
from plaid.exceptions import ApiException
```

The file I am trying to run is this, but I have tried many functions as I have found its not the function its the import statement:

```
from plaid import Client
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def plaid_link_view(request):
    # Initialize Plaid client
    client = Client(client_id=PLAID_CLIENT_ID, secret=PLAID_SECRET, environment=PLAID_ENV)

    # Create Link token for user interaction
    link_token_create_response = client.Link.Token.create(
        user={
            "client_user_id": request.user.id,  # Replace with user identification method
        },
        products=["transactions"],  # Adjust products based on your needs
    )
    link_token = link_token_create_response['link_token']

    # Render context with link_token for frontend integration
    context = {
        'link_token': link_token,
    }
    return render(request, 'plaid_link.html', context)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Everything imports fine.

Comment: Don't make us guess where the error is.  We don't know if the error happens inside code that you wrote yourself, or if it happens inside some other third-party package.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Following the documentation](https://github.com/plaid/plaid-python#calling-endpoints), it should look something like this:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from plaid import ApiClient, Configuration
from plaid.api.plaid_api import PlaidApi


def plaid_link_view(request):
    # Initialize Plaid client
    configuration = Configuration(
        host=PLAID_ENV,
        api_key={
            "clientId": PLAID_CLIENT_ID,
            "secret": PLAID_SECRET,
        },
    )
    api_client = ApiClient(configuration)
    client = PlaidApi(api_client)
    # Create Link token for user interaction
    link_token_create_response = client.link_token_create(
        user={
            "client_user_id": request.user.id,  # Replace with user identification method
        },
        products=["transactions"],  # Adjust products based on your needs
    )
    link_token = link_token_create_response["link_token"]

    # Render context with link_token for frontend integration
    context = {
        "link_token": link_token,
    }
    return render(request, "plaid_link.html", context)
```

You're probably following an outdated tutorial as [the api was changed 3 years ago](https://github.com/plaid/plaid-python/commit/9bbc84df94e6a8a7390411d4eeeb6fd05ce08c3b).